# Using Flask-HTTPAuth when serving a static folder

Tags: flask, flask-httpauth

I'm using Flask to serve a static folder:

```
from flask import Flask, send_from_directory
from flask_httpauth import HTTPBasicAuth

app = Flask(__name__,
            static_url_path='',
            static_folder='html_files')
...

@app.route('/')
@auth.login_required
def send_html_files():
    return send_from_directory('html_files', 'main.html')
```

I used the [first example in Flask-HTTPAuth docs](https://flask-httpauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) in order to add basic authentication to my website. Just a regular username and password is enough for me.

The problem is that the authentication dialog is not showing when the user go directly to http://localhost:5000/a/b/c (it works on http://localhost:5000/)

What is the proper way of doing this? On the other hand, what is the quick and dirty way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@app.route('/')` matches your root path only.

Try something like this to match every path:

```
@app.route('/<path:filename>')
@auth.login_required
def send_html_files(filename):  
    return send_from_directory('html_files', filename)
```

Comment: just figured it out by my own, but thanks a lot. BTW, how can I confiugre filename to be nullable so it will also work with localhost:5000/ ?